# Isssue in devportal api urls, after config load balancing in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Why after configuration loadbalancing in wso2 api manager, api urls that created and should eb tested is writen with localhost and not for example in gm.am.wso2.com?how we should call it from client?
And also now try out fails in devportal because all requests direct to localhost, so can not test in devportal
"https://localhost:8243/shaparak/1.0.0"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gateway URLs should be configured under `[[apim.gateway.environment]]` in deployment.toml file resides in `< APIM-Home >/repository/conf` directory. the default configuration is given below:

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://api.am.wso2.com:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"
```

For this particular issue, check if you have configured the correct `https_endpoint` under `[[apim.gateway.environment]]`

Comment: my hostname = "api.am.wso2.com" , so I set to endpoints to  "api.am.wso2.com" or "gw.am.wso2.com" that is in document?

Comment: You have to configure the `gw.am.wso2.com` in the above-mentioned Gateway Environment configurations. Update the `http_endpoint`,`https_endpoint`,`ws_endpoint`, and `wss_endpoint` for the moment. You don't have to change the `service_url`.

Comment: Thanks.just after change to "gw.am.wso2.com" in .144 & .115 server, should I set hostname in hosts in .166 (nginx server )?becuase now test api in devportal cuase error.@Athiththan

Comment: Add a Host entry for `gw.am.wso2.com` in the `.114` and `.115` nodes with the Nginx Node's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The devportal server URL which handles the HTTPS servlet traffic has been changed. But when you invoke the API calls (HTTP/HTTPS API traffic), they will be sent through the gateway (HTTPS port=8243). In the shared image, the "localhost" hostname indicates the gateway's hostname which uses the default value. Please make sure you have configured the hostname properly in the deployment.toml file.

Please refer [1] for further details on this topic.

[1]https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/